# I have a linux installation on an external drive. How can I plug it into a desktop and have it boot?

Tags: grub2, live-usb, external-hdd, bootable, portability

### Hardware:

- `Laptop` [ Daily driver ]
- `Desktop` [ Server - Normally has Windows installed ]
- `USB Thumb Drive` [ Linux Installation Medium ]
- `External Drive` [ Linux Installation Destination ]

### Situation:

1. `Laptop` boots `USB thumb drive`
2. Mount `External Drive` to `Laptop`
3. Install Linux to `External Drive`
4. Plug `External Drive` to `Desktop`
5. `Desktop` will not recognize or boot from `External Drive` [ Boot order has been set and configured ]

### Bad Solution:

1. `Desktop` boots `USB Thumb Drive`
2. Mount `External Drive` to `Desktop`
3. Reinstall Linux to `External Drive`

It will now boot, but only on that machine. It will also delete my previous installation, which I do not want to do.

### Question:

Rather than reinstall, how can I fix this existing Linux installation, so that this `Desktop` [ Preferably any x86/64 device ] will recognize and be able to boot from the `External Drive`?

Thanks.

### Edit:

I ended up doing a reinstall of OpenSuse Tumbleweed on the `External Drive` from my `Laptop`. For whatever reason, I was then able to use it on my `Desktop`.

I may have misdiagnosed why it was not working prior, but the previous OS on that external was Ubuntu. Take that for what its worth.

Comment: From the symptoms, I would guess that at least one of the systems involved uses UEFI-style booting. Would it be sufficient that the external drive is bootable on all UEFI-bootable systems, or do you need support for legacy BIOS boot too? If the former, then `sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable` once the installation is completed and system is booted from the external drive might be all you'll need. For the latter, is the partitioning scheme on the external drive MBR or GPT?

Comment: Most systems now are UEFI. Are both laptop & desktop UEFI? Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer in UEFI mode only installs grub boot loader to first drive, normally internal drive. That is ok if one drive or user is ok with all boot loaders on that one drive. But for second drives & particularly external drives that does not work. See old bug with various work arounds. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 If external gpt with an ESP, you need to reinstall grub to external drive. If not add ESP & use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub. Or new install.